# Copy file via scp from a remote machine that need root access (with remote root access disabled)

Tags: ssh, root, scp

I'm on the machine A, and I want to run a bash script from A to copy some files from B via `scp`. Those files are stored in a path that needs `root` access to be accessed but `root` remote access is disabled for `ssh` in B. I cannot change that configuration.

Standard `scp` statements do not work since I'm not asked to type B's `root` password during `scp` execution on A.

How can I do?

Comment: copy the file somewhere else where you have an access and then use `scp`.

Comment: ok, but how can I copy root protected on B file running a script from A? (not via shell)

Comment: probably you will need to configure `sudo` for that. It can work also non-interactive, without password or authenticate you using different means (`pam_ssh_agent_auth`).

Comment: Ok, but I cannot config machine B.

Comment: Then you will probably have to go down to use some `expect` script.

Comment: Do you have a user that can become root with sudo?

Comment: Yer @FrancisconSantos

Comment: Have you familiarized with ansible? One simple ansible can do that, If you need, I will post here a full step by step to install and create a ansible playbook to do it using a simple user with sudo privileges.

Comment: No @FrancisconSantos, I'm not

Comment: @Gilles, the question states server sshd_config can not be changed, yet this question was marked as duplicate of a question where all scoring answers instruct to change sshd_config. Certainly answers in the other question may be useful, but IMO this is NOT a duplicate of **that** question.

Comment: @AndrDevEK The accepted answer also discusses the case where the server configuration can't be changed, and there's another answer that explains how to set up a tunnel. I don't think we need to duplicate the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this to work on my box, but I'm not sure if `sudoers` option `requiretty` would break it.

On machine B create program that `sudo` will use to ask for passwords.
e.g. `/home/myname/askpass.sh`, `chmod` it `+x`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my_password"
```

On machine A create connect script that will establish the ssh connection for the `scp` and inject `sudo` + related commands into remote command.
e.g. call it `./fakessh.sh`, `chmod` it `+x`

```
#!/bin/bash

oldargs=( $@ )

newargs=( )

while : ; do
  [ "${oldargs[0]}" == "scp" ] && break

  newargs+=( "${oldargs[0]}" )
  oldargs=( "${oldargs[@]:1}" )
done

newargs+=( 'export SUDO_ASKPASS=/home/myname/askpass.sh' \; exec sudo -A -- "${oldargs[@]}" )

exec ssh "${newargs[@]}"
```

Note that the script above references `/home/myname/askpass.sh`, update path as required.

Now run `scp` almost normally:

```
scp -S ./fakessh.sh user@hostname:/etc/shadow ./
```

This does work for me. YMMV.

I can think of other hacks if you can run something like `ncat` or `socat` with `sudo`, and point `scp` at the custom listening port, but that's getting silly from security point.

Comment: Ok but in that way I have to type unencrypted password in the file

Comment: @superciccio14 yes, example as it was written is far from great. You can get `/home/myname/askpass.sh` to read password from a named pipe and supply the password to that named pipe in another ssh session. You probably could pass the password via environment, which is a little better than saving it in a file but still not as good as with a named pipe because it will remain in memory longer and be readable by `ps` and such tools. I'm afraid if box is not under your control then no method is safe.